# Error de IErrorInfo.GetDescription con E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo la siguiente función la cual recibe la ruta de un archivo Excel para abrirlo y leerlo para ir agregando usuarios, lo ejecuto en mi proyecto desde Visual Studio y corre sin problemas, al momento de llevarlo al servidor donde debera de trabajar me muestra el error que muestro, ya estuve buscando y no encontre palabras reservadas que pueda estar utilizando, pues el manejo de base de datos lo hago por medio de LINQ ¿Alguna idea?

```
    public static string AgregarUsuarios(string DocExcel)
{
    try
    {
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaBuscar"] + DocExcel;
        SECDataContext SEC = new SECDataContext();
        string respuesta = "";
        ExcelQueryFactory Librito = new ExcelQueryFactory(path);
        var resultado = (from datito in Librito.Worksheet("Hoja1")
                         let elmeeeeent = new EntidadHojaExcel
                         {
                             NumeroEmpleadoXX = datito["Numero"],
                             PuestoXX = datito["Puesto"],
                             UnidadXX = datito["Unidad"],
                             FechaIngresoXX = datito["FechaIn"],
                             NombreXX = datito["Nombre"]
                         }
                         select elmeeeeent).ToList();
        if (resultado.Count > 0)
        {
            int VNE;
            int UA = 0, UNA = 0, UE = 0;
            foreach (EntidadHojaExcel D in resultado)
            {
                if (D.NumeroEmpleadoXX == "" || D.NumeroEmpleadoXX == null)
                {
                    UNA++;
                }
                else
                {
                    VNE = ValidaNumeroEmpleado(Convert.ToInt32(D.NumeroEmpleadoXX));
                    if (VNE > 0)
                    {
                        Puesto Puesto = (from p in SEC.Puesto where p.NombreP.Replace(" ","").ToLower() == D.PuestoXX.Replace(" ","").ToLower() select p).SingleOrDefault();
                        Unidad Unidad = (from u in SEC.Unidad where u.NombreUN.Replace(" ","") == D.UnidadXX.Replace(" ","") select u).SingleOrDefault();
                        Usuario U = new Usuario
                        {
                            IDP = Puesto.IDP,
                            IDR = 1,
                            IDUN = Unidad.IDUN,
                            NumeroEmpleadoU = Convert.ToInt32(D.NumeroEmpleadoXX),
                            NombreU = D.NombreXX,
                            EstatusU = true,
                            FechaIngresoU = Convert.ToDateTime(D.FechaIngresoXX)

                        };
                        SEC.Usuario.InsertOnSubmit(U);
                        SEC.SubmitChanges();
                        UA++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        UE++;
                    }
                }                                        
            }
            respuesta = "Usuarios Agregados: " + UA + " Usuarios No Agregados(Sin número de empleado): " + UNA + " Usuarios Existentes: " + UE;
        }
        return respuesta;
    }            
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaBuscar"] + DocExcel;
        Log(e.Message + "AgregarUsuarios " + path);
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

> Error de IErrorInfo.GetDescription con E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Comment: Hola. Se ha verificado que la ruta y el nombre del archivo Excel en el servidor son correctas?

Comment: Se ha verificado si en el servidor está instalado la misma versión del controlador OleDB que en el entorno de desarrollo?

Comment: Hola, si de hecho era eso como tomo la ruta de un WebConfig estaba mal, pero entre en panico porque por lo que busque en Internet ese error hace referencia a uso de palabras reservadas en las consultas o cosas así .

Comment: Hola, si se ha solucionado el problema puedes responderla y cerrarla? O si quieres voy a publicar una respuesta. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error es un mensaje típico de error OleDB. Revisa que la ruta y el nombre del archivo Excel en el servidor son correctas y si en el servidor está instalado la misma versión del controlador OleDB que en el entorno de desarrollo.